# browser.windows.create is returning undefined?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

browser.windows.create api is returning undefined for some of my users.
It is not occuring all the time and i am also not able to reproduce.
Does anyone knows the exact issue?

I tried this in my progam in service worker script(MV3)

> browser.windows.create({
> url: request.url,
> type: 'popup',
> height: Math.round(request.height),
> width: Math.round(request.width),
> left: Math.round(request.left),
> top: Math.round(request.top)
> }, function (windowData) {
> callback(windowData)
> })

Comment: It probably means there's an error, maybe some parameter is undefined so Math.round produces `NaN`. Check `chrome.runtime.lastError` in the callback or use `catch` on the Promise.

Comment: height and width are hardocoded as 640 and 400, and left is defined as (screen.width - width), top as (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2), and is passed via browser.runtime.sendMessage to service worker.
I already added try/catch to above code, and found that windowData is returning undefined sometimes.

Comment: try { browser.windows.create({ url: request.url, type: 'popup', height: Math.round(request.height), width: Math.round(request.width), left: Math.round(request.left), top: Math.round(request.top) }, function (windowData) { callback(windowData) }) } catch (e) { console.log(e);}

Comment: Yep, it's incorrect. You need to add `await` before browser.windows.create.

Comment: i uses chrome.runtime.lastError to fetch the error and the error is "Invalid value for bounds. Bounds must be at least 50% within visible screen space"